# Does Ubuntu now use bpfilter or netfilter?

Tags: networking, kernel, firewall

I'm trying to put together a firewall/router using netinstall of Ubuntu 18.10 with bpfilter.  I know it's packaged by default with kernel >=4.18 these days, but I'm a little confused about how to specify it rather than netfilter.

Does anybody know?

For starters:

```
root@ubuntu1810:/home/localuser# uname -r
4.18.0-12-generic
```

And also :

```
root@ubuntu1810:/home/localuser# dmesg | grep bpfilter
[  969.576326] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 14099
```

Also just noticed this:

```
# lsmod | grep bp
bpfilter               16384  0
```

So that's good, but when I search for `netfilter` I get a lot of `/proc` sources

```
root@ubuntu1810:/home/localuser# find / -name netfilter
/usr/include/linux/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/include/linux/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/include/net/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/include/uapi/linux/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/net/ipv6/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/net/bridge/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/net/ipv4/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/net/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/net/decnet/netfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12-generic/include/config/netfilter
/proc/sys/net/netfilter
/proc/1/task/1/net/netfilter
/proc/1/net/netfilter
/proc/2/task/2/net/netfilter
/proc/2/net/netfilter
/proc/3/task/3/net/netfilter
/proc/3/net/netfilter
/proc/14462/task/14462/net/netfilter
/proc/14462/net/netfilter
/lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/net/ipv6/netfilter
/lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter
/lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter
/lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/net/netfilter
/lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/net/decnet/netfilter
```

but then also I can find: (although no /proc)

```
root@ubuntu1810:/home/localuser# find / -name bpfilter
/sys/module/bpfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/net/ipv4/bpfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12/net/bpfilter
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-12-generic/include/config/bpfilter
/lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/net/bpfilter
```

And also, if I run `iptables` rules these should control whatever firewall is running, correct?  I'm setting up `csf` with `webmin`.

Can anybody clear this up for me please?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think I may have answered my own question through research.  From what I gleam from many articles, 1) bpfilter is included in the kernel and runs, but does not currently have general functionality to any appreciable degree as of 4.18,  and 2) netfilter is still included as the default kernel firewall along with iptables rules compatibility  --- Please correct me if I'm wrong!